# Trigger backbone event on loss of focus from set of fields

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Trying to trigger a backbone event when ever someone clicks outside one of two `input` fields. This triggers properly for clicking outside, but I want it to NOT trigger when you click the OTHER field.

```
var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    'blur input': 'blurInputs'
  },

  blurInputs: function(){
    if ( $('input.description').is(":focus") || $('input.amount').is(":focus") ){
      // do nothing
    } else {
      // do something
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Rather than checking for blur events, have you tried listening for click events?

Comment: I haven't yet and that would probably work, but it's a lot more messy to implement. If click anywhere except one of those inputs...

Comment: Well the one idea would be add a transparent div to your page with a z-index higher than everything but the two inputs, or other elements you care about, then you just have to listen for clicks on that one div. You could hide it when the user clicks on it, and show it when the inputs gain focus.

Comment: Yeah that's not a terrible idea. You lose the ability to click on other things though. The first click is a "clear" click and then you have to click again to actually do the thing you were intending to do.  Blur is perfect (if it worked right)

Comment: I see your point. One thing that I usually do my backbone apps is have a global click bind function that every click event is routed to. This would allow you to do your input logic check. Otherwise, if you're really stuck on the blur solution, I think the hack is your only option.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is probably because the blur event is fired before the other input box obtains focus.

A possible hack would be to wait a few milliseconds before you check if the input boxes have focus

```
blurInputs: function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (this.$('input.description').is(':focus') || this.$('input.amount').is(':focus')) {
      // do nothing
    } else {
      // do something
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

Comment: This DOES work but definitely feels like a hack. It will have to do for now though.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Paul's answer but it worked well for my use case

```
  onBlur: function(e) {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if(self.$el.find('input:focus').length == 0) {
        console.log("BLUR");
      }
    }, 500);
  },
```